# Order entitydatasource records

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to order entitydatasource records like this: `orderby="Product_Num"` 
but it says:

> 'Product_Num' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[productmodel.Products(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection.

So, it means that It cannot order collection of Products. It needs some kind of subquery, but I'm not sure what exactly does it need.

Comment: please give more source code.